# Copy and translate polygonz records according to attributes

Tags: shapefile, polygon, copy, pyshp

I have a polygonz shapefile. I have some records which represents building footprints. I want to copy records according to their attributes 'number of storeys value'. For example, a record has storey value as 4. I want to copy footprint 3 times (storey-1) and translate these polygonzs along z axis according to floor heights (which is a constant value as 3m in any case). I did what I want for a record manually using pyshp. However, I have 1282 building footprints as polygon records and I want a more automatic way. Could you suggest any solution?
Here is what I achieved as picture[image]

Here is my code

```
import shapefile

w = shapefile.Writer(shapeType=shapefile.POLYGONZ)
w.field('Name')

w.record('Polygon1')
w.poly([[[570290.3825960495, 4535093.086859931, 0], [570306.3562040495, 4535114.818163932, 0], [570337.0239320495, 4535092.45711193, 0], [570321.0603200498, 4535070.52588793, 0], [570290.3825960495, 4535093.086859931, 0]]], shapeType=15)

w.record('Polygon2')
w.poly([[[570290.3825960495, 4535093.086859931, 3], [570306.3562040495, 4535114.818163932, 3], [570337.0239320495, 4535092.45711193, 3], [570321.0603200498, 4535070.52588793, 3], [570290.3825960495, 4535093.086859931, 3]]], shapeType=15)

w.record('Polygon3')
w.poly([[[570290.3825960495, 4535093.086859931, 6], [570306.3562040495, 4535114.818163932, 6], [570337.0239320495, 4535092.45711193, 6], [570321.0603200498, 4535070.52588793, 6], [570290.3825960495, 4535093.086859931, 6]]], shapeType=15)

w.record('Polygon4')
w.poly([[[570290.3825960495, 4535093.086859931, 9], [570306.3562040495, 4535114.818163932, 9], [570337.0239320495, 4535092.45711193, 9], [570321.0603200498, 4535070.52588793, 9], [570290.3825960495, 4535093.086859931, 9]]], shapeType=15)

w.save("C:/Users/ziyau/Desktop/cesium uygulama/fpz")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following could be a good starting point:

```
import shapefile

r = shapefile.Reader('footprints.shp')
w = shapefile.Writer(shapeType=shapefile.POLYGONZ)
w.autoBalance = 1
w.field('NAME','C','10')

for i, shapeRec in enumerate(r.shapeRecords()):
    shape = shapeRec.shape
    rec = shapeRec.record

    fields = r.fields[1:]
    field_names = [field[0] for field in fields]
    field_name = 'storeys'
    field_index = field_names.index(field_name)

    storeys = rec[field_index]
    for j in range(storeys):
        new_shape = []
        for k in range(len(shape.points)):
            coords = shape.points[k]
            x, y = float(coords[0]), float(coords[1])
            zeta = shape.z[k]
            z_new = float(zeta) + j * 3 # 3 = floor heights
            new_coords = [x, y, z_new]
            new_shape.append(new_coords)
        w.poly(parts=[new_shape], shapeType=shapefile.POLYGONZ)
        w.record('Polygon{}'.format(j+1))

w.save("storeys.shp")
```

Comment: yes that was exactly what I want thank you @afalciano